Fields Missing on Task Global Action
I have created two record types on Task "One" and "Two". I have created two page layouts for each "One" and "Two". I cant use Lightning Pages for dynamic fields for Task, this is why I took this approach.
The issue is, Task uses fields from Event and Activity. I can add the fields from each of these objects to the Task Page layouts, but I can't add them to the Global Action for Tasks.
Take a custom field called Activity.Interaction_Address__c. I can add this field to the Page Layout for Task, but I cannot see this field to add it to the Global action I have created for Task. I have to create new "Task" fields on the Activity object, and I can add some fields to my Task Global Action, but some won't let me. And these are configured the same in FLS (aka I have access to AnswerTime__c and can see it in Global Action layout while I have access to Answer_Date_Time_Formula__c and cannot see it in Global Action layout)
My questions are:

I currently have two global actions: "New Task One" and "New Task Two". Is there a way to combine these two Actions into a single action "New Task" that lets the user pick a record type "One" or "Two" and launch the appropriate layout based on the record type?
Is there a way to add the Activity fields I need to the Task Global Action? I cant create new fields on the Task object, so surely there is a way to add fields from Activity?

